# Tree structure variable in time

Tags: database-design, oracle11g, hierarchical-data

I have a simple tree structure: manager/team leader/team member. But this structure is variable in time: team member 1 is a member of team 1 e. g. from (YYYY.MM.DD) 2013.01.01 to 2013.03.31 and later from 2013.04.01 is a member of team 2. And possible use case is to move the hole team (with members) from one manager to another. I have to remember the structure of the organisation in an each snapshot of time.

What is the best model to implement this in oracle database (11gR2)? Possible use cases are: adding, removing a person on each level and moving a person/group on each level. And of course showing the structure, showing a boss on each level, showing members on each level, showing history of membership in a period of time.

Best Regards,

Jacek

Answer (score 0):

There are time domain extensions for Oracle, though they are very slow and a bit clumsy in my experience. Have a look at Oracle temporal support on their site.

What it does, rather simply, is to add a date range to the primary key. This date range is the validity range. When a fact changes, you terminate the existing row, which may be detected by having a far future date (Dec 31st 9999), by putting in an end date of now() or whenever you want the date to be, and adding a new row, that has a begin date of now(), and an end date far into the future (Dec 31st 9999).

When querying, always look for rows where the date of interest is greater than equal to the begin date, and earlier than the end date.

This works for any data structure.

Where you wish to have simple queries on the current date, add a view which selects appropriately.

Good luck!